# Como setar apenas uma linha da coluna na qual todos os valores dessa coluna são iguais?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Estou tentando setar a coluna `ocupado` apenas uma linha de cada vez, algo como:

```
update suite set ocupado = 'S' where tipo = 'i';
```

Mas essa instrução muda todas as linhas da coluna `ocupado` onde `tipo` é `i`, e não é isso que eu quero. Eu quero que apenas uma única linha entre estas seja alterada para "S", as demais que atendam a condição devem permanecer inalteradas.

É um sistema de reservas, não importa qual linha seja mudada, mas deve ser apenas uma que atenda as condições acima. Na próxima execução desta *query* ele fará com outra linha porque esta deixa de atender a condição.

```
+--+-----+--------+
|id|tipo |ocupado |
+-----------------+
|01| i   | N      | <- alteraria só esta 
|02| i   | N      |
|03| c   | N      |
|04| c   | N      |
+-----------------+
```

Comment: precisa explicar melhor, usar termos mais corretos, quem sabe dar algum exemplo do que acontece. A forma descrita não faz sentido. E o código deveria fazer oque parece querer, mas diz que não faz. Campo e coluna são a mesma coisa. Elementos? Não sei o que isto quer dizer em um banco de dados, principalmente em uma coluna, seriam linhas? Você quer que em apenas um linha `ocupado` mude para `S`? Qual seria essa linha?

Comment: Isso mesmo! Eu quero que apenas uma linha da coluna ocupado mude para S.

Comment: Qual linha?....

Comment: Qualquer uma, mas que seja somente uma a cada execução do comando sql. Para explicar melhor, isso seria um hotel que a cada reserva de suíte o status da suite muda para: "Suíte ocupada? Sim", Suíte ocupada? Não.

Comment: @Jfé bote um LIMIT 1 no fim da query então.

Comment: Já fiz isso, mas quando executa outra vez o status não muda pois o limite é 1.

Comment: Usa o id cara, ele é único

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Botando fé no que explicou nos comentários seria isto:

```
update suite set ocupado = 'S' where tipo = 'i' and ocupado <> 'S' limit 1;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Update/Limit2.sql).

Assim você garante que faça só em uma linha de cada vez, sempre se o tipo for o selecionado e que não faça onde já tem um `N`.

Comment: Muito agradecido por estar me ajudando! Não serviu porque nesse caso só existem dois valores(status) que são `N` e `S`, quando o valor de `ocupado` não for `S` logo ele será `N`, então esse comando não vai mudar o valor de `ocupado` para `S` pois só tem dois valores para `ocupado`.

Comment: É, eu esqueci de trocar

Comment: Funcionou!! Sei nem como agradecer...